# APEX class - code coverage in Developer edition

Tags: apex, class, code, code-coverage

I am fairly new in Salesforce, exposed to developer edition only. I would like to know - whether there is any code coverage requirement for an APEX class to be used? I am aware that in Enterprise edition, the requirement is 75%. But I do not know the limit for Developer edition.

I ask because - I have written a Class and when I copy the code and paste in Developer Console > Debug > Open Execute anonymous window, I get expected results. However, when I call the apex class from VisualForce component, I am not getting desired result. The class is supposed to return the Name of a borrower of a book based on given book name. But the borrower's name is returned as blank when called from VF component.

Would appreciate if someone can tell me whether I need to write a test class and get the code coverage to get it working. Thanks.

Comment: kindly share your code, both VF and apex.

Comment: @Mahmood, link for my new thread is - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/146387/38613. Would appreciate if you have a look. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code coverage has nothing to do with the functionality of your code.

The scenario you describe can only be a result of your code.

The code coverage is a tool for understand how much of your code is covered by tests.  It does not change the behaviour of your code.

Comment: Thanks Nick, for prompt feedback. I will return to this forum with my code.

Comment: @Guha I'd suggest closing this question (i.e. marking it as answered) and starting a new question.  The issue will be completely different to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Code coverage comes into picture when deploying to a production organization.
There seems to some problem with your code. Functionality of your doesn't depend on the code coverage.

Comment: Thanks Samir, for prompt feedback. I will return to this forum with my code.